# Object destructuring and immediately return

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Is it correct to destruct props from an object and immediately return it like this:
`const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...{ name, phone, shift} = state.employeeForm
});`

Works pretty fine but my IDE is going mad. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good. Since javascript syntax is rapidly evolving and offers large syntax variations, IDEs are still catching up.

Answer (score 1):

What about destructuring it via function's params?
Spread operator catches the `irrelevant` key as well, basically it creates copy of the object:

//EDIT: Added two more destructuring examples, I also discovered that your function with spread operator leaks variables to global namespace for some reason, at least here in the SO snippet:

```js
let state = {
  form: {
    name: 'test',
    phone: 123,
    shift: true,
    irrelevant: false,
  }
};

(function () {
  let fun2 = ({form: {name, phone, shift}}) => ({name, phone, shift});
  console.log('fun2', fun2(state));
})();

try {
  console.log(name, phone, shift);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('no leak');
}

(function () {
  let fun3 = state => {
    let {name, phone, shift} = state.form;
    return {name, phone, shift};
  };
  console.log('fun3', fun3(state));
})();

try {
  console.log(name, phone, shift);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('no leak');
}

(function () {
  let fun = state => ({
    ...{name, phone, shift} = state.form
  });
  console.log('fun', fun(state));
})();

try {
  console.log('leak:', name, phone, shift);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('no leak');
}
```

Comment: Yeah sure, but i'm trying to keep my `map` function as simple as possible, in order to possibility that my `state` will be changed in future

Comment: Unfortunately fun4 was using variables which leaked to global namespace... it's weird, isn't it ?

Comment: @AndriiSkrebets What about `fun2` it's simple I think, also your function with spread operator for some reason leaks variables to global namespace

Comment: At first I wrote my `map` function like your `func2` example, then tried to simplify and got what about i asked for. Also check about leaking vars, i my case there are not. But its good to know about such possible behavior